# All webview content printed in one page

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.android

**Case**: User should be able to view and print pdf

**My solution**: I am opening PDF inside `Webview` with the help of `docs.google.com/gview`. Below is my code

Set up Webview

```
    string url = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
    string gview = $"https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url={url}";
    mWebView.LoadUrl(gview);
```

Print PDF

```
    var printMgr = (PrintManager)GetSystemService(PrintService);
    printMgr.Print("print", mWebView.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter("print"), null);
```

Below is the screenshot. As you can see PDF loads just fine

[image]

**Problem**

When I want to print PDF, all the PDF pages are printed in one paper which you can see below

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestion, including different library for displaying/printing pdf or suggestion in Java or Kotlin, I can convert them to C#.

Comment: I try to search some info about printing web pages, but it likes your code, just print web pages in one page, I find one article about printing, that you can take a look, may be helpful to you:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/native-printing-with-android/

Answer (score 1):

I would not print the web page but print the PDF directly as when printing the web page it just sees it as a longer web page and knows nothing about the content.

Use a custom print adapter instead, but instead of drawing a PDF to print you can just use the existing PDF you already have.

See for details https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html